# Dans quel cas l'expression « grand bien lui fasse » s'applique-t-elle le mieux?

Tags: expressions

Dans quel cas l'expression « grand bien lui fasse » s'applique-t-elle le mieux ? Serait-il aussi possible d'indiquer l'intention se cachant derrière cette expression (sarcasme, bienveillance, etc) ?

Comment: Est-ce que je suis le seul à la connaître comme « grand bien lui *en* fasse » ?

Comment: @Nikana Vraisemblablement, oui. (ici, en tous cas)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) la définit comme « que cela lui soit profitable », avec l'annotation « souvent par ironie ». Elle est assez voisine de l'anglais *good for him*, mais nettement plus rare.

Je ne trouve pas que cette expression soit [particulièrement dédaigneuse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/dans-quel-cas-lexpression-grand-bien-lui-fasse-sapplique-t-elle-le-mieux/1176#1176), c'est juste une des connotations possibles. En regardant [quelques textes modernes](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22grand%20bien%20lui%20fasse%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1984,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_fr), je vois un éventail de significations assez varié. La plupart ont en commun le faible intérêt que porte le locuteur à la situation décrite, ou au moins un certain détachement du locuteur, mais ce désintérêt ou détachement n'est pas forcément du dédain.

> *Qu'il épouse qui il voudra, grand bien lui fasse ! Mais qu'il laisse ma fille tranquille.* ([Ioannis Kondylakis, *Patoukhas*, trad. Pierre et Vassiliki Coavoux](http://books.google.com/books?id=5dQeGCrEKIsC&pg=PA119&dq=%22grand+bien+lui+fasse%22&hl=en&ei=waJxTsiyAc7E4gT0j621CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&ved=0CFsQ6AEwCA))

*Peu m'importe qui il épouse, du moment que ce n'est pas ma fille.*

> *C'est Conrad Gugy qui prend la direction à présent. Grand bien lui fasse ! Moi, je suis devenu notaire et dois te dire que le commerce va mal.* ([Bernard Andrès](http://books.google.com/books?id=EH8w1GqTbmYC&pg=PA366&dq=%22grand+bien+lui+fasse%22&hl=en&ei=waJxTsiyAc7E4gT0j621CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22grand%20bien%20lui%20fasse%22&f=false))

*Il est arrivé une bonne chose à Conrad Gugy, mais pas à moi.*

> *Grand bien lui fasse, il le paiera de sa vie.* ([Jean-Yves Maleuvre](http://books.google.com/books?id=eJd8rsYwgZQC&pg=PA78&dq=%22grand+bien+lui+fasse%22&hl=en&ei=waJxTsiyAc7E4gT0j621CQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22grand%20bien%20lui%20fasse%22&f=false))

Ici l'emploi est ironique, et ne marque pas le désintérêt du locuteur : le détachement est plutôt entre ce qu'a fait la personne (à priori une bonne chose) et ce qui lui est arrivé au final (une mauvaise chose).

> *En grand seigneur, François Bérubé avait décidé de sauver son île. Grand bien lui fasse, mais Marthe n'avait que faire de cette croisade.* ([Jacques Savoie](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vdz8C2JHCXoC&pg=PA42&dq=%22grand+bien+lui+fasse%22&hl=en&ei=bapxTq3sGIrCtAaB9-jlBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDEQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22grand%20bien%20lui%20fasse%22&f=false))

La phrase est au style indirect libre : ce qu'a fait François Bérubé est peut-être une bonne chose pour lui, mais n'est pas important pour Marthe.

À noter que l'expression se conjugue : *grand bien te fasse*, *grand bien leur fasse*, ... Elle est rare, mais ce depuis longtemps ; elle n'est pas particulièrement désuette.

[grand bien lui fasse,grand bien leur fasse,grand bien te fasse http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=grand%20bien%20lui%20fasse%2Cgrand%20bien%20leur%20fasse%2Cgrand%20bien%20te%20fasse&corpus=7&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=grand+bien+lui+fasse%2Cgrand+bien+leur+fasse%2Cgrand+bien+te+fasse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)

Comment: Rien à ajouter : tout est là !

Comment: Tu as des actions chez google ? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Cette expression est devenue assez rare en langage courant. Je l’entends ou l’utilise encore de temps à autre uniquement sur le mode du sarcasme lorsqu’on pense qu’un sujet de conversation à propos d’une personne n’a pas d’intérêt :

« *La voisine du 6<sup>e</sup> est enceinte.*
*— Grand bien lui fasse !* »

On peut aussi répondre à quelqu’un « *Grand bien te/vous fasse* » :

« *Je collectionne les fèves*
*– Grand bien te fasse !* »

Comment: Est-ce un désintérêt envers la personne ou envers le sujet de conversation ? Il me semblait que c'était plutôt envers la personne à qui on adresse son *grand bien*... non ?

Answer (score 3):

L'expression « grand bien lui fasse » est [définie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bien/substantif) (voir section `I.C.` ou chercher *fasse*) comme ironique.

[Une autre définition](http://fr.thefreedictionary.com/bien) précise qu'elle *se dit quand quelqu'un s'intéresse à une chose que soi-même on dédaigne*.

La notion de dédain est en effet celle qu'on cherche à exprimer : on ne porte en réalité aucun intérêt à ce qui est arrivé à l'autre personne. Les [exemples de Benoit](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1176) illustrent ça parfaitement.

Comment: (+1) Excellente réponse qui insiste sur le fait que le locuteur indique par cette expression qu'il ne souhaite *en réalité* pas le bien qu'il énonce. Cela ne signifie pas non plus de la haine, mais un clair désintérêt.